# multiple numberDisplays from group

Tags: dc.js

With the following data, how can I bin by the class column (high, middle, low) and total the values

[image]

and display each total with its own `dc.numberDisplay` in this form?

[image]

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of just text values, use the text itself.

Comment: You probably shouldn't tag with d3.js if you want dc.js-specific answers. That tag reaches a much broader audience. I'll remove the extra tag and hope to answer later in the day (although this is actually not trivial because you're generating N numberDisplays from the data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is pretty close.

Because the number display only displays one number, we need to generate a `div` for each value we want to display.

First, the usual crossfilter stuff, creating a group that bins by class:

```
var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select('pre#data').text());
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
})

var cf = crossfilter(data);

var classDim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.class; });
var classGroup = classDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Now we're going to need to pull the individual values out as if they were different groups. We can create a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) that pulls an individual value by index. Note: this won't work if the number of groups changes over time. But that usually doesn't happen.

```
function subgroup(group, i) {
  return {
    value: function() {
      return group.all()[i];
    }
  };
}
```

Now we need to know the index for each bin we're interested in:

```
var bins = ['high', 'middle', 'low'];
var indices = {};
classGroup.all().forEach(function(kv, i) {
  if(bins.indexOf(kv.key) >= 0)
    indices[kv.key] = i;
})
```

We'll build a div for each of those bins, coloring it and adding a heading based on the name of the bin, and using an array of colors for the background color:

```
var colors = ['rgb(219,41,0)', 'rgb(255,143,31)', 'rgb(255,198,82)'];
var display = d3.select('#numbers').selectAll('div').data(bins);
display.enter().append('div')
    .attr('class', 'display')
    .style('background-color', function(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    })
  .append('span')
    .attr('class', 'heading')
    .text(function(d) { return d.toUpperCase(); });
```

Here's the CSS to get it to look approximately as you showed above:

```
.display {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font: 36pt sans-serif;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.display span.heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font: 8pt sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

Now, finally, we can actually generate the `numberDisplay` widgets for each of those divs. This is the easy part!

```
display.each(function(d) {
  var numberDisplay = dc.numberDisplay(this)
    .group(subgroup(classGroup, indices[d]))
    .formatNumber(d3.format('d'));
});
dc.renderAll();
```

Screenshot below.

[image: multiple number display]

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aw9h8d93/9/

Comment: Thanks Gordon) That's what we need.