# dc.js numberdisplay filter percentage

Tags: dc.js

I'm new into javascript and dc.js and currently having difficulty creating a numberDisplay that only looks at a particular value in a column within my data.

I have created a dashboard with a number of different charts but I'm currently stuck on the final numberDisplays that will also filter along with the rest of the charts.

My data includes two fields in a similar format to the below, and I'm looking to create a percentage numberDisplay only for SLA's that are "2 days".

So I would expect the numberDisplay to return a percentage of "2 days" within the entire group, so it would show 30% (10/30)

I've searched and tried different solutions but the only thing I've managed to do so far is to display the overall Sum for all SLA's.

```
var data = [{
"sla": "2 days",
    "team": "hr",
    "hits": 7
}, {
"sla": "2 days",
    "team": "finance",
    "hits": 1
}, {
"sla": "2 days",
    "team": "finance",
    "hits": 2
}, {
"sla": "3-4 days",
    "team": "hr",
    "hits": 5
}, {
"sla": "3-4 days",
    "team": "hr",
    "hits": 4
}, {
"sla": "5 days",
    "team": "finance",
    "hits": 3
}, {
"sla": "5 days",
    "team": "hr",
    "hits": 8
}];
```

There are around 6-7 different possible entries in SLA, and I'm currently only looking to create number displays for 2 or 3 of them.

What would be the quickest/easiest solution to do this?

I have created a basic jsfiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/kevinelphick/owx2L1wt/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=owx2L1wt

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with the total sum of hits for 2 days, but I still can't find a way to divide this into the total Sum

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be blank? It's a little over-complicated, but the `numberDisplay` will [look for group.value; if that exists, it will call it; otherwise it will call group.all() and compute the maximum bin according to chart.ordering(). Then it will transform the result using `chart.valueAccessor()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/number-display.js#L99-L100). So if you want to display something arbitrary, supply an object for the group that returns the value you want, and supply the identity function for the value accessor.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question with the fiddle link, I can only manage to show the total sum for the SLA = "2 days", I'm still finding it difficult to work in the groupAll reduceSum figure to create the percentage calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a little bit cleaner to use an ordinary reduction and use a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to pull out the individual value that you want.

Here is a wrapper that takes a group and a key and returns a groupAll-style group with a `value` function which returns the bin at that key:

```
function choose_bin(group, key) {
  return {
    value: function() {
      return group.all().filter(kv => kv.key === key)[0].value;
    }
  }
}
```

In order to calculate the percentage, we also need the total number of hits; we can use `dimension.groupAll()` to get that:

```
var allHits = slaDimension.groupAll().reduceSum(d => d.hits);
```

I am assuming here that you don't want these numbers filtered by the pie chart (because it would only display 0% or 100% that way). So we use the same dimension and group, because [a group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters).

We'll define `sla_2days` based on the wrapper function:

```
var sla_2days = choose_bin(slaGroup, '2 days')
```

And finally we'll define the `valueAccessor` of the `numberDisplay` to calculate a percentage:

```
slaNumberDisplay
  .group(sla_2days)
  .valueAccessor(x => (x / allHits.value())*100)
```

Fork of your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/sa2mL8wh/3/

Comment: That is excellent! Perfect, I'm sure I'll be using this in future for a number of other dashboards I'll be creating too! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to found a solution for this thanks to some guidance from Gordon's comment and some further research on this site:

I added some functions to the group:

```
var slaGroup1 = all.reduce(
  function(p, v) {
    p.count += v.hits;
    p.slasum += (v.sla == "2 days" ? v.hits : 0);
    p.slaPercent = p.count ? p.slasum/p.count : 0;
    return p;
    console.log(p.failures);
  },
  function(p, v) {
    p.count -= v.hits;
    p.slasum -= (v.sla == "2 days" ? v.hits : 0);
    p.slaPercent = p.count ? p.slasum/p.count : 0;
    return p;
  },
  function() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      slasum: 0,
      slaPercent: 0
    };
  }
);
```

and then my NumberDisplay value accessor:

```
slaNumberDisplay
  .group(slaGroup1)
  .formatNumber(d3.format(".1%"))
  .valueAccessor(function (x) {return x.slaPercent;});
```

I'm sure there's a more dynamic way to do this though? If I wanted to create multiple number displays for different criteria? Could I create the functions outside of the group, and the group calls the functions with the criteria set inside brackets? And I could also remove the percentage from the functions too, and simply do this in the value Accessor.

Comment: Yeah, personally I'd prefer to leave the group reduction function alone and create a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to pull just the bin that you want. It's a little more complicated, but I did something similar in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998197/multiple-numberdisplays-from-group For some reason your fiddle is still not working or I'd work up a quick demo for you.

Comment: If you could that would be great! hopefully this works: https://jsfiddle.net/kevinelphick/ovqr5pku/